# How to solve Issue with Open Cover with Dotnet Framework 4.8?

Tags: .net, code-coverage, mstest, .net-4.8, opencover

I have a Unit Test Project setup for Dotnet Framework 4.8. (MSTEST).

Im trying to setup open cover for the same, I am able to generate report with non async methods without any issues.
When I have a Async method in  any of my test method. It get stuck and nothing happens.

My bat file to test is as given below.

```
SET OPENC_OVER=C:\Users\vish\.nuget\packages\opencover\4.7.922\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe 

SET REPORT_GENERATOR=C:\Users\vish\.dotnet\tools\ReportGenerator.exe

SET TEST_ASSEMBLY="D:\VP\Server\Station\Station.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Station.UnitTest.dll" 

set LIBRARY_TO_MONITOR="D:\VP\Server\Station\Station.UnitTest\bin\Debug\Station.Processor.dll"
 



%OPENC_OVER%  -register:user -log:info -target:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"  -targetargs:"test %TEST_ASSEMBLY% --no-build --logger:trx" -filter:"+[Station.Processor]*" -output:coverage.xml

%REPORT_GENERATOR% -reports:coverage.xml -targetdir:coverage-report -reporttypes:HTML
```

Why it doesn't work for async method? Is there any solution for it?

I have tried installing coverlet and NCover , but both are unable to install.
Should I try any other tools?